# Getting route undefined error for POST after upgrade from Laravel 4.2 to 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, post, controller, routes

I am upgrading my app from Laravel 4.2 => 5.x
I was using routes such as

```
Route::post('/cancelaccount',["as"=>"/cancelaccount",'uses'=>'UserController@cancelAccount']);
```

But when I try to load the page, I get "/cancelaccount" undefined error. I do not get this error if it's a GET request, I have problem with all my POST requests which are submitting to controller methods.

Currently as a workaround, I am replacing all actions to Controller@method format from URL format

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you try it once without the leading slash in route as 'cancelaccount' and see if it works?

Comment: Maybe because of `CSRF Protection` ?

Comment: @Musa, I tried removing "/" but result is same. I still get route undefined error!

Comment: @mimo, wont CSRF give me TokenMismatch exception rather than route undefined?

Comment: You get an `undefined error` so it could be anything

Answer (score 1):

So after searching high and low for the answer on internet, I realized that I was looking at wrong place. I was looking at Route for an answer which is not where the problem lies.

So here's the answer if some poor soul is facing the same issue. Route undefined error will be encountered only for Form actions. In Laravel 5, Form "action" is reserved for only Controller methods. If you want to POST to named route, Open your form like this

```
Form::open('route'=>'your-named-route')
```

In my case I changed my form definition to

```
Form::open('route'=>'/cancelaccount','method'=>'post')
```

Ofcourse you can still use `Form::open('action'=>'Controller@method')`

Hope this helps!